# It could/can/might be that

Tags: modal-verbs

A scientist speculates on a particular matter, saying:

1. It **could** be that the first living organisms evolved independently in different places—we just don't know.

Can I replace the "could" with "can" or "might"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*W can X* means "W is able to X" - it's simply expressing ability.

*W could X* means "W is able to X if some condition Y is true" - the Y can be expressed earlier or later in the conversation, or omitted because the speaker/writer assumes it's understood.

*W might X* basically means "It's possible W will X, if X is allowed".

So, given:

> It could be that the first living organisms evolved independently in different places—we just don't know.

Is there a condition that would make or cause "the first living organisms to evolve independently" - or is there some *if ...* sentence related to this? If so, *could* works.

Did you mention or is it known that something would allow "the first living organisms to evolve independently"?  For example, X for the organisms might allow independent evolution; if something like that is going on, *might* works.

Are you simply saying it's *possible* without much more details? Then use *can*.

Answer (score 1):

All are possible, but they have a different "likelihood" connotation, you can use them to express such variation.

*Can* sounds more probable than *could*, whereas *might* sounds less probable.

In essence, *can* express an already established potential. About a scientifc theory, it would express that it is one of the explanation that is deemed as a candidate for being "the standard one", i.e. it's on the "short list" of candidate theories.

Using *could*, conditional of *can*, would mean "it's on the long list" of the candidate theories. It's a bit less certain, there are some conditions to fulfill that are not there yet.

Using *may*, or *might* (even less probable than *may*), would imply to me that it's not currently considered, but one could think of it this way and, maybe, become a good theory after some more detailed research.